# Filter AngularJS Route

Tags: angularjs, sharepoint, url-routing, sharepoint-2013

I have a routing base like this

```
{ url: /Tasks,
  templateUrl: /Pages/Tasks.html,
  nav:1,
  main:0,
  isvisible:true
},
{ url: /Requests,
  templateUrl: /Pages/Requests.html,
  nav:2,
  main:0,
  isvisible:true
},
{ url: /Projects,
  templateUrl: /Pages/Projects.html,
  nav:3,
  main:0,
  isvisible:true
},
{ url: /NewTask,
  templateUrl: /Pages/NewTasks.html,
  nav:1,
  main:1,
  isvisible:true
}....
```

It is a long route like look up fields and reference key is main and for example New Task is subitem for Tasks.

I want to get them in a controller and at first need to get main routes which are have main property equal to 0 (Tasks, Requests, Projects) and i have a click scope and when i click "Tasks" I want to filter route items like "News Tasks" because it's main property equals to 1. I hope I could tell my map.

I think a filter for that as a SharePoint developer and I want to write a query like

```
$route.where(route.main == 0 && isvisible == true).select(url)
```

for main routes and

```
$route.where(route.main == 1 && isvisible == true).select(url)
```

for Tasks menu's sub routes.

Can anyone help for that? I am new with Angular but cannot imagine filter for routing.

Thanks, really

Comment: I couldn't understand your question, can you please elaborate more. Maybe give a specific example with your html and controller code (or pseudo-code)

Comment: Did you imagine routing json? For example New Task referenced to Tasks by main property. It looks nav proprty of Tasks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my basic an easy answer. I will write here for beginners like me

```
$scope.selectTab = function (tabID) {
    $scope.tab = tabID;
    $scope.subMenus = routes.filter(function (route) {
        return route.main === tabID;
    });
}
```